# Python collections ValuesView abc: why doesn't it inherit from Iterable?

Tags: python, collections, abc

I was just checking out some docs on [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html)s for a project of mine, where I need to do some type-related work. Those are the official docs about the [`ValuesView`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.ValuesView) type, in both Python 2 and 3:

and [this](https://hg.python.org/releases/2.7.11/file/9213c70c67d2/Lib/_abcoll.py#l479) is the source (Python 2, but same happens in Python 3)

I was very puzzled about the `ValuesView` interface, because from a
logical standpoint it should inherit from `Iterable`, IMHO (it's even
got the `__iter__` Mixin method); on the contrary the docs say that it just
inherits from `MappingView`, which inherits from `Sized`, which doesn't
inherit from `Iterable`.

So I fired up my 2.7 interpreter:

```
>>> from collections import Iterable
>>> d = {1:2, 3:4}
>>> isinstance(d.viewvalues(), Iterable) 
True
>>>
```

It looks `Iterable`, after all, because of `Iterable`'s own subclasshook.

But I don't understand why `ValuesView` isn't explicitly `Iterable`. Other `ABC`s, like `Sequence` or `Set`, are explicitly `Iterable`. Is there some arcane reason behind that, or it's just a documentation+implementation shortcoming for a little-used feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 3.7.2, it inherits from both `MappingView` and `Collection` which in turn inherits from (among others) `Iterable`. Someone listened to you.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue32467 "I'm going forward with this because it does offer a sense of neatness (in comparison to KeysView and ItemsView) and it might avoid a pedantic StackOverflow question somewhere down the line." -> actually, the question had already been asked :-)